# How to create Bar Chart for Ipad application in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, ipad

Can anybody let me know how to create Bar Chart in Xcode for Ipad Application?
If anybody can post sample code or a sample it would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.
Krish

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Quartz, it will take some time to create it.

1. Subclass a UIView
2. Put your Quartz code inside the `drawRect:` method.

Ask specific questions if you get stuck, I would be happy to help.